# Store/use WPF App.config in different directory

Tags: c#, wpf, path, app-config

Simply,
I have a WPF application which, when built, outputs main.exe along with a main.exe.config file (that gets auto generated from App.config).

App.config contains important app configuration*, that being the <probing> element.

The problem is: Everything works as expected until you delete the main.exe.config file that gets auto generated with the main.exe - probing stops working. (I'm aiming to make it only 1 file.)

The question: **Is it possible to store this app configuration in a different path OR somehow embed the configuration inside the actual application?**

I've done some research with the ConfigurationManager, but didn't find what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution could be the following:

- Set `Build Action` to `Embedded Resource` for the `App.config` file.
- Remove `StartupUri` attribute from `Application` in `App.xaml` file.
- Create a `Program.cs` file with this content:

```cs
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Text;

namespace YourNamespace
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static readonly Assembly thisAssembly = typeof(Program).Assembly;

        private static readonly string appConfigFilePath = $"{thisAssembly.Location}.config";
        private static readonly string appConfigResourceName = $"{thisAssembly.GetName().Name}.App.config";

        [STAThread]
        public static int Main(string[] args)
        {
            if (!AppConfigFileExists())
            {
                SaveAppConfigFile(LoadAppConfigFileFromResource());
            }

            App app = new App()
            {
                StartupUri = new Uri("/MainWindow.xaml", UriKind.Relative)
            };

            return app.Run();
        }

        private static bool AppConfigFileExists()
        {
            return File.Exists(appConfigFilePath);
        }

        private static string LoadAppConfigFileFromResource()
        {
            string stringContent = String.Empty;

            using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            using (Stream stream = thisAssembly.GetManifestResourceStream(appConfigResourceName))
            {
                stream.CopyTo(memoryStream);

                byte[] byteContent =
                    memoryStream
                        .ToArray()
                        .Skip(Encoding.UTF8.GetPreamble().Length)
                        .ToArray();

                stringContent = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(byteContent);
            }

            return stringContent;
        }

        private static void SaveAppConfigFile(string content)
        {
            File.WriteAllText(appConfigFilePath, content);
        }
    }
}
```

- In the *Project Properties* window set the *Startup object* to `YourNamespace.Program`
- Append this at the end your `.csproj` file but before `</Project>` XML node:

```xml
  <PropertyGroup>
    <AppConfigFileSourcePath>$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)App.config</AppConfigFileSourcePath>
    <AppConfigFileTargetPath>$(TargetPath).config</AppConfigFileTargetPath>
    <BuildDependsOn>
      CopyAppConfigFile;
      $(BuildDependsOn)
    </BuildDependsOn>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Target Name="CopyAppConfigFile">
    <Message Importance="high" Text="Copying App.config file..." />
    <Message Importance="high" Text="$(AppConfigFileSourcePath)" />
    <Message Importance="high" Text="$(AppConfigFileTargetPath)" />
    <Copy SourceFiles="$(AppConfigFileSourcePath)" DestinationFiles="$(AppConfigFileTargetPath)" />
  </Target>
```

With these steps the config file will be there after build by default but if the file is deleted then before the application starts the config file will be recreated from resource.

I tested it with an `AppSettings` item and the value was properly loaded and displayed.